# CSS Jquery Scroll Sticky Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have an issue with a WordPress menu not sticking at the top.  My JQuery adds the correct class to the div but it doesn't stick for some reason.

Here's the html pre-scroll:

```
<div id="site-navigation-wrap" class="navbar-style-one wpex-dropdowns-caret clr">
```

Once scrolled the JQuery clearly works as the class is added:

```
<div id="site-navigation-wrap" class="navbar-style-one wpex-dropdowns-caret clr stickymcstickface">
```

...and here is the css:

```
.navbar-style-one .stickymcstickface {
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

I have tried playing with the z-index just in case it is hidden beneath something but that doesn't help.  I also tried it without the space and with only the stickmcstickface class but to no avail.

Any ideas where I may have gone wrong?

Best Regards

Dave

Comment: can you give me demo where you tried these?

Comment: Hi Hidayt - currently on an internal testing server only so can't share sorry

Comment: Without a demo we probably won't be able to help you further. @Mihai T's answer would've been mine too, but if it still doesn't work it's likely that a CSS rule on another element is causing this.

Comment: agree with @FabianSchultz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem in CSS . write classes without space between them

`.navbar-style-one .stickymcstickface` to **`.navbar-style-one.stickymcstickface`**

this is because both classes are of the same element.

your current code would've worked if the element with class `.stickymcstickface` would've been a child of the element with class `.navbar-style-one` .

but in your case both classes belong to `#site-navigation-wrap` so you should write them without space between them

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I have tried it both with and without that space but not working either way.
Cheers

Comment: @user3160485 hmm. that's strange. can you post a working sample of your code ? so i can help you better? or inspect element and see if the styles applied to your fixed class are overwritten by other styles

Comment: Do you have an #id which is taking priority?